# Check multiple Oracle DB conenction using PHP 5.4 and OCI8

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I want to create a simple web page which checks the availability of my several Oracle instances in my lab using PHP 5.4 and OCI 8.

In general it works for all instnaces that are up, but if I have an instance that is down the script exit and the other instances are not  checked!??

Let me show you my little code:

```
<?php
$c1_ORCL11 = oci_connect("system", "mypassword", 'ORCL11');
$c2_ORCL21 = oci_connect("system", "mypassword", 'ORCL21');
$c3_ORCL23 = oci_connect("system", "mypassword", 'ORCL23');

function check_connect ($conn, $sid)
{
  if (!$conn) {
     $m = oci_error();
     echo $m['message'], "\n";
     break;
 }
 else {
    print "$sid: Connected to Oracle!<BR>";
 }
 // Close the Oracle connection
 oci_close($conn);
}

check_connect($c1_ORCL11,'ORCL11');
check_connect($c3_ORCL23,'ORCL23');
check_connect($c2_ORCL21,'ORCL22');
?>
```

Instances ORCL11 and ORCL21 are UP and ORCL23 is DOWN. If I execute the code I got the following output:

```
ORCL11: Connected to Oracle!
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

The idea was to get also "ORCL21: Connected to Oracle!", but the code exit if I can not connect to an instance. If I change the order to:

```
check_connect($c1_ORCL11,'ORCL11');
check_connect($c2_ORCL21,'ORCL21');
check_connect($c3_ORCL23,'ORCL23');
```

I get the following output:

```
ORCL11: Connected to Oracle!
ORCL21: Connected to Oracle!
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

and if I change the order to:

```
check_connect($c3_ORCL23,'ORCL23');
check_connect($c1_ORCL11,'ORCL11');
check_connect($c2_ORCL21,'ORCL21');

ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

So, If I have a bunch of Instances and the 1st one in the list is DOWN, the other instances are not shown on my web page even if there are UP and running :-(

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Regards,

Ralf

Answer (score 0):

After posting the question I saw my mistake ... strange, looked before some hours and didn't find it ... anyway ... it worked fine after removing the "break;" command within the if case. My assumption was to just break out of the if case and continue but it looks like the break exit the whole code at this stage!

Here is the complete code an the result:

```
<?php
$c1_ORCL11 = oci_connect("system", "<mypasswd>", 'ORCL11');
$c2_ORCL21 = oci_connect("system", "<mypasswd>", 'ORCL21');
$c3_ORCL23 = oci_connect("system", "<mypasswd>", 'ORCL23');

function check_connect ($conn, $sid)
{
  if (!$conn) {
     $m = oci_error();
     echo "$sid: ", $m['message'], "<BR>";
     //break;
 }
 else {
    print "$sid: Connected to Oracle!<BR>";
 }
 // Close the Oracle connection
 oci_close($conn);
}

check_connect($c3_ORCL23,'ORCL23');
check_connect($c1_ORCL11,'ORCL11');
check_connect($c2_ORCL21,'ORCL21');
?>
```

The Output:

```
ORCL23: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
ORCL11: Connected to Oracle!
ORCL21: Connected to Oracle!
```

Regards,

Ralf

Comment: You may want to tweak your OS network and Oracle Net parameters to reduce any timeout periods so the program doesn't hang waiting for network timeouts.  There are a couple of parameters mentioned in https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionha

Comment: Hi Christopher, good hint - will check sqlnet.ora and set the timeout parameter! Regards, Ralf